# Deleting data from two linked tables in SQL DB using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, datatables

I need to write a stored procedure to delete rows (updated rows) of data older than a specific date (>6 months), in two tables linked together using a primary key in SQL DB server.

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Linked with a primary key

Comment: So why can't you write your procedure? What is your *actual* question? [why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Comment: There's no problem with deleting from multiple tables in the same stored procedure. Just write your stored procedure as normal, and include the separate delete statements  for both tables. Make sure you delete them in an order that won't cause constraint violations based on their key relationship. Is there any specific part of this you are struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

you have two linked tables: Table1 and Table2, and there's a common primary key, let's call it PrimaryKeyColumn. You also want to delete rows where the "UpdatedDate" column is older than 6 months. Here's an example of how you can create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteOldDataFromLinkedTables
AS
BEGIN
    -- Calculate the date 6 months ago
    DECLARE @CutoffDate DATETIME
    SET @CutoffDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())

    -- Delete data from the first table (Table1)
    DELETE T1
    FROM LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.Table1 AS T1
    JOIN LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.Table2 AS T2 ON T1.PrimaryKeyColumn = T2.PrimaryKeyColumn
    WHERE T1.UpdatedDate < @CutoffDate;

    -- Delete data from the second table (Table2)
    DELETE FROM LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.Table2
    WHERE UpdatedDate < @CutoffDate;
END
```

1. We calculate the @CutoffDate as the current date minus 6 months.
2. We use a DELETE statement with a JOIN to delete rows from Table1
   that have matching primary key values in Table2 and where the
   "UpdatedDate" is older than the @CutoffDate.
3. We also delete rows from Table2 based on the "UpdatedDate" alone.
   You can choose to delete from one or both tables based on your
   requirements.
4. Make sure to replace LinkedServer, DatabaseName, Table1, Table2,
   PrimaryKeyColumn, and UpdatedDate with the appropriate names in your
   setup.

   ```
   EXEC DeleteOldDataFromLinkedTables;
   ```